# Find whether an element occurs n/4 times in n element array

Tags: algorithm

I was asked this question. I tried to use the majority element method, but it didn't work for me. Please provide some hints.

Comment: how fast it needs to run? O(n)? O(n lg n)? any thing?

Comment: Not possible to answer without the requirements (e.g. deterministic, memory requirements, time requirements)

Comment: what kind of elements do you have?

Comment: A specific element *x*, or determine if there is any element that accounts for at least 25% of the values?

Comment: You can accept answer if it helps you. Also the future visitors will be benefited with that.

Answer (score 6):

1. Find out the median in `O(n)` time.
2. Partition the array based on that median using 3-way partition.
3. if median itself is the required element then done

    else

    On both the partition (left and right to the median) apply the majority element algorithm. (In your case find the element which appears more than n/4 times in an array of n/2) . Both will run in `O(n)` time.

Total time would be `3*O(n)=O(n)`.
Hope this helps :)

Comment: +1 Nice answer. I editted it a bit for readability, hope you don't mind.